# Deriving the Equation for the Depth to Which an Object Falls

Tags: harmonic-functions, kinematics

For a body of mass m kg, show that the depth to which the body would fall if attached to a rope, with a length of l meters. The depth is given by the model:

$$d= \frac{2ml \pm l \cdot \sqrt{4m^2 + 600m}}{150} + l$$

The rope is specially designed and its modulus of elasticity is known from specifications.

For the purposes of this problem, assume that the rope is stretched to twice its natural length by a body of 75kg hanging at rest from the free end.

Define one assumption before beginning the problem.

---

I know that if I rearrange the equation I get, $75(d-l)^2 - 2ml(d-l) + 2ml = 0$. This indicated to me that the problem has probably come from a kinematic equation. However, once I reach this point I am stuck. I don't know how to progress any further into the question. Would simple harmonic motion equations be required? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any other ways to approach this?

Comment: Yes you can use SHM but energy is probably easier

Comment: The question is from a chapter on SHM so I'm thinking that might me the route I need to take. But I don't know how to approach it either way.

Comment: If you know about elastic energy and conservation of energy, then that is the best way. If not, then you have to use SHM

Comment: I'm not familiar with elastic energy. How would I start approaching the question with SHM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26575/discussion-between-ron-and-david-quinn).

Comment: I am not familiar with elastic energy. I'm pretty sure the question must be solved with SHM. However, I do not how to start with SHM. Would you be able to provide the first few steps?

Comment: You should know that models of deformation of materials rarely have predictability past 0.1% deformation past original length.

Answer (score 0):

The energy approach is like this:

The elastic potential energy is given by $$EPE=\frac {\lambda x^2}{2l}$$ where $\lambda$ Is the modulus of elasticicty, in this case $75g$, $x$ is the extension, and $l$ is the natural length.

The particle starts from rest and falls, coming instantaneously to rest after falling a distance $d$. Assuming no air resistance, total initial energy $=$ total final energy, and kinetic energy is zero initially and finally, so we have: $$0=\frac{75g(d-l)^2}{2l}-mgd$$

Can you take it from there?